# Having trouble with check = True using on_raw_reaction_add

Tags: discord.py

I'm having trouble with my check = True. I can't seem to get identify the member making the reaction. Here is the code:

````
@bot.command()
async def buy(ctx):
    reaction = await ctx.reply('Pick \U0001f44d')
    
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    def check(pl):
        return pl == payload.member and str(payload.emoji) == '\U0001f44d'
    try:
        pl = await bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', timeout=3.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send("no one picked")
            await payload.member.send("you")
    else:
        if payload.emoji == '\U0001f44d':
            await channel.send("you picked 1")```

My I idea is to have someone call the command and then allowing more than one member to be able to react thus the bot.event. What am I doing wrong for my check to not = True?
````

Comment: maybe your check function is flawed to never return true

Comment: That's the issue,  but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: is the argument pl you pass in of type `discord.Member`?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member - I guess it's not. How would I call on the member making the reaction then?

Comment: what exactly is `pl` here?

Comment: is it also a different `payload` of type `RawReactionActionEvent`?

Comment: I thought the `wait_for` could be a variable so I simply named it 'pl' thus `check(pl)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an issue with the check
I suggest to replace your check with this:

```py
check = lambda payload: payload.message_id == msg.id and payload.channel_id == ctx.channel.id and str(payload.emoji) == '\U0001f44d'

payload = await client.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', check=check, timeout=30)
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work